# PlaceOrder Transactions

Tags: hyperledger-composer

can you help me with this? I am trying to implement a transaction to place an order as the one you have on the vehicle- lifecycle-network however it is not working. I am able to submit the order; however when I try to update the status, I get an error saying that the order is not part of the collection ID; however, it works if I can create it with the add asset process. the same happen when testing the vehicle- lifecycle-network in the online playground. please advise.

Comment: Post a sample of the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to resolve to a Registry that does not exist - or is actually an abstract definition.

eg.

Both the Vehicle asset and the PrivateVehicleTransfer transaction accept relationships to the abstract participant composer.base.Person:

```
asset Vehicle identified by vin {
  o String vin
  o VehicleDetails vehicleDetails
  o VehicleStatus vehicleStatus
  --> Person owner optional
  o String numberPlate optional
  o String suspiciousMessage optional
  o VehicleTransferLogEntry[] logEntries optional
}

transaction PrivateVehicleTransfer extends VehicleTransaction {
  --> Person seller
  --> Person buyer
  o String specialNotes optional
}
```

The error message means that we're trying to look for (in this case) the composer.base.Person participant registry - but it does not exist:
Error: Object with ID 'Participant:composer.base.Person' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist

That participant registry does not exist because we do not create registries for abstract types.

We are looking for this registry because the vehicles supplied originally contain fully qualified relationships, but they do not include the right type:

```
{
"$class": "org.vda.Vehicle",
"vin": "1234",
"vehicleDetails": {
"$class": "org.vda.VehicleDetails",
"make": "Ford",
"modelType": "Ka",
"colour": "Red",
"vin": "1234",
"bodyType": "Hatchback",
"taxationClass": "PETROL_CAR",
"co2": 89,
"typeOfFuel": "Petrol",
"numberOfSeats": 5
},
"vehicleStatus": "ACTIVE",
"owner": "resource:composer.base.Person#bob@bob.com", <-- this is the problem
"numberPlate": "AA12 AAA"
},
```

etc

The relationships in the owner field need to contain the right type, eg, a Participant that extends from abstract 'Person' - for example PrivateOwner below would be the correct relationship:

```
"owner": "resource:org.acme.vehicle.lifecycle.PrivateOwner#bob@bob.com"
```